# Does TLS always use the same algorithms for both directions?

Tags: tls

Does TLS always use the same algorithms for both client to server and server to client communication or can they be different?

E.g. is it possible that the client uses *AES256* to cipher the data before sending it, while the server employs *RC4*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cipher used is the same in both directions and thus the encryption algorithm is the same too. In detail: the client proposes some ciphers it is willing to use and the server picks one of these ciphers and sends it back to the client.

Comment: I wonder if there's any utility in such a disparity of cipher suite usage. I can't think of one, but it is an interesting concept to mull over.

Comment: @Polynomial Just guessing: One small embedded device with a hardware AES engine, one with hardware RC4?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Is this a technical limitation of the standard or is it just that it is always done that way, eg best practice?

Comment: @MaxRied: it is a limitation which is there from the beginning. I guess it never made much sense to have it different  since this would make the protocol more complex without much gain: different algorithms might require different symmetric keys which would make key exchange more complex etc. And I don't see the need for it: the aim of choosing the cipher is not to get the most secure but to use the fastest one which still offers the security needed for the use case.

Comment: I don't doubt that, I was just curious.

Comment: Another potential security challenge is that ciphers have generally been studied as secure when used in isolation. If you re-use the same key for two different ciphers you may open yourself up to some very interesting security holes.

Comment: @Polynomial: SSL/TLS uses different keys (and IVs when applicable) in each direction anyway; see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/what-is-the-purpose-of-four-different-secrets-shared-by-client-and-server-in-ssl . For completeness: if client _authentication_ is used, which is fairly rare, the (publickey) algorithm for client auth is independent of that for server auth.